# Passing props to component without quotes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, uikit, vuejs3

Hope everyone is safe and coding at home.

I am building a custom component for my personal use that basically implements the UI Kit framework functionalities regarding buttons.

Please find the code below:

BaseButton.vue

```
<template>
  <button v-if="!modal" :class="start + bType + bSize + displayBlock" :disabled="disable">
    <span v-show="icon !== ''" :uk-icon="'icon: ' + icon"></span> <slot></slot>
  </button>
  <a v-else :class="start + bType + bSize + displayBlock" :disabled="disable" href="#base-modal" uk-toggle>
    <span v-show="icon !== ''" :uk-icon="'icon: ' + icon"></span> <slot></slot>
  </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },

    disable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    block: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    modal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      start: "uk-button",
      displayBlock: this.block === true ? " uk-width-1-1" : "",
      bType:
        this.type === "" ? " uk-button-default " : " uk-button-" + this.type,
      bSize: this.size === "" ? "" : " uk-button-" + this.size,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

App.vue

`<tg-btn :block="true" :type="'primary'" :size="'large'" :icon="'cog'">Test button</tg-btn>`

The thing is, right now the only way I can pass the string props to my component is using double quotes and then single quotes to wrap the string. This isn't really saving me time, and therefore I would like to know the following:

- Is there any way to pass strings without using quotes two times? like this:

`<tg-btn :block="true" :type="primary" :size="large" :icon="cog">Test button</tg-btn>`

- Also, is there any way to do something like the following? which technology should I use:

`<tg-btn block large primary icon="trash">Test button</tg-btn>`

Thank you very much for your help!
Stay safe!

Regards,
T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some `props` you have to remove the binding sign `:`, for props that have boolean values as values you could keep them without value if the value is true :

```
<tg-btn block type="primary" size="large" icon="cog">Test button</tg-btn>
```